# Compare sample categories/distribution from two different data sources

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, categorical-data

I have ethnicity from two different data sources distributed over 5 categories. One data source provides it at a higher level, and covers more population. Second data source provides it at a lower level, and covers less population. But since it is at a lower level, it could be more accurate at that level.

For example:

```
Source  BroadLevel  DeepLevel   Af-Am   Asian   White   Hispanic    Other   Count
Source1     1       NA          8.7     10.4    80.9    0.0         0       NA
Source2     1       1.1         8.2     10.4    81.2    0.2         0       120
Source2     1       1.2         8.9     10.4    80.5    0.2         0       110
```

We need to show ethnicity at `DeepLevel`, however my manager do not want to differ much from the **Source1** which is widely accepted at the `BroadLevel`. So here is what he wants, if the numbers at `DeepLevel` do not differ much (He is not sure about the definition of "much", let's assume confidence level 90%, error limits +- 10% ) from numbers at `BroadLevel`, then show the distribution at `DeepLevel` otherwise, report that `DeepLevel` is too volatile and non-trust-able and report same `BroadLevel` distribution for each `DeepLevel` under it. For each `BroadLevel` there can be one or more (say up to 10) `Deeplevel`. Also note that for each `DeepLevel`, sample size is > 100 (shown under variable `count`). `BroadLevel` would always have a sample size > sum of all the `DeepLevel` sample sizes, but is not available.

So is there any test which I can use to find out if the two distribution do not differ "much". I believe something like [this](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chi2samp.htm) could be useful, but not sure.

PS: I may have written few things incorrectly, however, pardon my statistical naivety.